# Xamarin XAML add items to ScrollView by buttonclick using bindings

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am new at making phone app´s and are trying Xamarin out for the first time.

I have a page with a ScrollView witch i want to add items to each time a button is pressed, but I cannot figure out a way to accomplish this.

I am trying to maintain an MVVM setup as far as possible for easier maintenance.

At the moment I have something like this:

App.cs -> Just setting `MainPage = new TestView();`

TestView.xaml.cs ->

```
namespace ScrollViewTest.View {
public partial class ScrollViewView : ContentPage {
    public ScrollViewView() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
  }
}
```

TestView.xaml

```
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
  <viewModel:ScrollViewModel></viewModel:ScrollViewModel>
</ContentPage.BindingContext>
<StackLayout>
  <Label Text="Test App"></Label>
  <ScrollView>
    <Label Text="someItem"></Label>
    <Label Text="someItem2"></Label>
    <Label Text="someItem3"></Label>
</ScrollView>
<Button Command="{Binding AddToScrollViewCommand}" Text="Add to ScrollView">                          </Button>
```

In testViewModel I am handeling the command.

I have no problem in changing the labels and stuff like that, using bindings, but I am stuck trying to add new labels to my ScrollView

Anyone have a way to make this work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the ListView component.
https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.ListView/

it is both scrollable by default and has the feature to add new elements at runtime :)

edit:

```
<ListView x:Name="EmployeeView" ItemSource="{Binding someList}" />
```

and in the viewmodel

```
ObservableCollection<string> someList {get; set;} = new ObservableCollection<string>();
```

something like that anyways ;)

Comment: Thanks, this sovled my issue.